Why do some claim that the law of non-contradiction is non-trivially unprovable?
By non-trivially unprovable, I mean that unprovable unless proven by virtue of being an axiom or an inference rule. If a logic has an inference rule or an axiom that is not stated as ¬(A ∧ ¬A), but it is nonetheless semantically identical to it (on it's own), then that counts as the LNC being feautured in its basic assertions, meaning any proof of the LNC as stated above would be circular, and thus trivial.
As an example, let's say you had an axiom like AxA, where x is some connective corresponding to the same truth table as the main connective in the LNC; well then, we'd have the LNC in a hidden form as an axiom. Or, take the negation introduction inference rule in natural deduction, that negates any sentence that proves a contradiction; this inference rule is just the LNC in the form of an inference rule. So, both of these examples could allow for the non-circular syntactic derivation of ¬(A ∧ ¬A), but semantically it would circular; semantically,¬(A ∧ ¬A) would just be a reformulation of a basic assumption of the logic, and thus the belief of the LNC being non-trivially unprovable would not be countered by such examples.
The people who claim that the law of non-contradiction (LNC) is non-trivially unprovable, claim so because they maintain that one cannot prove the LNC without (in some sense) using it. I don't see how that's the case, but I get the intuition behind it.
Imagine this kind of hypothetical proof:

a
b
Therefore, LNC.

I imagine the skeptics would say that the proof is invalid because, without starting with the LNC, then the proof cannot be carried out, given that ~a and ~b are possible, and if one or both of them are true, then that would invalidate the proof.
But I don't see that. At step one, we have that a is true, and potentially that ~a is true (potentially true referring to given what we know right now, it may be true, not true in some world). Because ~a is potentially true, we also have that ~LNC is potentially true at this juncture.  At step two, we have that b is true, and potentially that ~b is true. At step 3 we have that the LNC is true, and now we no longer have the potentiality that ~a, ~b and ~LNC are true.
We do not depend on the falsity of ~a and ~b to prove LNC; we merely depend on the truth of a and b to prove the LNC (and thus, we do not depend on the LNC to prove the LNC). The falsity of ~a, ~b and ~LNC fall out of that proof as a consequence, but their falsity was not necessary for it.
But I am surely not the first to think like this, and I wonder what has been said for and against this kind of thinking. If I am not mistaken, I have read somewhere that Frege (attempted to) prove the LNC (and the LEM) via the Law of Identity, which would place him in agreement with me (at least at some point in his thinking). I am more interested in what the disagreers have to say, however. So, can one non-trivially, non-circularly prove the LNC?
EDIT:
The answers by Mauro and Bumble are helpful, but they do not quite answer the question. The answers show how the LNC can be proven without being taken as an axiom. However, this was my thinking for the get-go. I am more interested in the contrary views; that proving the LNC is somehow wrong or impossible. See this Wikipedia article for an example of this, that states some believe it can neither be proven nor disproven. How come?
EDIT 2:
I edited the start of the question to more loosely and correctly state what counts as trivial/circular proofs of the LNC.

Axioms are never “proved”, trivially or non trivially. Axioms are asserted. You can’t even begin to talk about the notion of proof and truth and falsity without presupposing logic (otherwise, those notions become meaningless). The LMC is one of the fundamental tenets of logic.

If all it takes for LNC to be "non-trivially proved" is that it is not listed as an axiom then it is certainly "non-trivially provable". Many standard axiomatizations of classical propositional logic do not include LNC, and it is provable from them. To make this remotely interesting, "some" should specify what else can and/or cannot be used to prove LNC "non-trivially".

I don't understand at all what the structure of your "proof" is supposed to be. Are 1 and 2 premises of the proof? (If so, you are proving the LNC conditionally on the truth of A and B.) Which logical step are you using to infer 3 from 1 and 2?

@Pilcrow Yes, 1 and 2 are the premises (whatever they be, though they will be derivable from some logic). I do not know which logical step is being used, because it is not a proof, it is a sketch of a proof; a hypothetical proof. It was formulated merely so that I could talk about the irrelevance of the possibility of ~a and ~b being true.

The law of non-contradiction one must suppose... because every successful logical system needs an immune system to reject what yields falsum and accept what yields truesum. Falsehood, in an intuitive logical system, acts like a protoplasmic poison.

I don't understand why using something in your proof of it is a problem. Things that work, work, and things that don't work, don't. If it didn't work, it would disprove itself. If your argument isn't about things that actually do something, it's rubbish anyway.

It could be said that in a more relative sense LNC is non-trivially unprovable if you always discern the Hegelian dialectic sublative differance between the Fregean relativized senses of propositions including their negations in such a way that negation can never or seldom invoked just like Aquinas suggested never assert, seldom negate, always differentiate, similar to Derrida's thesis and most phenomenologists' like Husserl..

@Conifold I see that you are right now, my original question was too narrow. Now that I have seen the ways that the LNC can sneak into the basic assumptions of a logic without feauturing as an axiom stated like ¬(A ∧ ¬A), I see that the spirit of my question cannot be captured by my original formulation.

Aristotle characterized LNC as "indemonstrable", but not in terms of non-provability under suitable constraints. He argued that any assertion already presupposes LNC as a condition of its possibility/meaningfulness because assertion that does not rule out its negative asserts nothing, see SEP, LNC as Indemonstrable. But this sort of meta-interpretation cannot be captured by first order logical formulas, ¬(A ∧ ¬A) or any other. And examples of 'true contradictions' suggest that even on it Aristotle may be claiming too much.

More of an extended comment than an answer (Mauro and Bumble both gave excellent treatments of your question).
Your stated goal is for evidence that the LNC is "non-trivially unprovable":

By non-trivially unprovable, I mean that unprovable unless proven by virtue of being an axiom.

You then have this to say about the current answers by Mauro and Bumble (emphasis mine):

The answers by Mauro and Bumble are helpful, but they do not quite answer the question. The answers show how the LNC can be proven without being taken as an axiom. However, this was my thinking for the get-go. I am more interested in the contrary views; that proving the LNC is somehow wrong or impossible.

So let's put this in simple logical form to make it precise:
NP(x):= x is non-trivially unprovable

P(x):= x is provable without being an axiom
P(x) → ¬NP(x)
P(x) (per your statment re: mauro's and bumble's answers)
∴ ¬NP(x)
Taking x=LNC, we see we have a "disproof" of the non-trivial unprovability of LNC.
Not sure what else you are looking for.

(Dec 1, 2024): Addendum on semantics and LNC
@user110391 clarified their intent for this question:

...the LNC might be semantically sneaking into the syntactic proof of it

Thus, the purely syntactic non-trivial proofs by Mauro/Bumble were not getting to the core issue for the OP (and hence also my above line of reasoning on why OP should accept their answers).
From a semantic viewpoint, indeed the LNC is non-trivially unprovable if one accepts the Principle of Bivalence

Principle of Bivalence: Every proposition must have a truth value selected from the set {True, False}.

This principle reflects the common sense/classical notion that we cannot have truth gluts, gaps, or extra values, all of which are allowed in non-bivalent/non-classical logics.
However, we run into a chicken-and-egg issue in that LNC and the choice of logical/semantic system are inextricably intertwined. Choosing a  non-bivalent semantics (e.g., non-standard Boolean logic, LP, supervaluationism, etc) requires rejecting the LNC or extra rules to allow it (which themselves import LNC).
So our semantics must contain within it the ability to prove the LNC, but that means the LNC not non-trivially provable.
However, there isn't anything special about LNC in this regard, as there are many instances of "Among N propositions, pick X as axioms and you can derive N-X as theorems" (and X is almost or completely arbitrary subset of the N).

What? P(x) is the same as NP(x) in the terminology established by my question, but you are saying P(x) implies the negation of NP(x). P(x) means x is proven, and x is not an axiom. NP(x) means x is proven, and it is proven non-trivially, which (in this post means), it is proven without being an axiom. Was there a typo in your answer perhaps? [1/3]

[2/3] Besides that, how does your answer touch on my edit at all? My question is very simple and can be abstracted like this: I have a belief B, but I know of people who believe ~B. I want arguments for and against B/~B. Here, B is the belief that the LNC can be non-trivially proven. I have this belief, but the linked-to Wikipedia article espouses the contrary belief. Discussion of this has begun happening in both Mauro and Bumble's answers and in their comment sections, which you can look at to get what the crux of this question is.

[3/3] Mauro and Bumble showed that from a syntactical standpoint, the LNC can be proven non-trivially, and perhaps you think that should be the end of it. I guess my question is so strictly formulated that you are technically right; that is the end of it. But as we see in my discussion with Bumble and Mauro, the LNC might be semantically sneaking into the syntactic proof of it; or even syntactically sneaking in as an inference rule, as opposed to an axiom, in which case the example is not adhering to the spirit of my question; "are there non-circular proofs of the LNC?"

@user110391 — yes, NP has an unfortunate typo :-/ corrected. And yes, you were seeking an argument to show why LNC is NP. You said Mauro and Bumble showed the LNC is in fact not NP since they derived it non tivially. Therefore, I wasn’t sure what else you needed. Seems like (a) the answers actually don’t show what you thought in your edit or (b) there is this semantic/syntactic distinction you are looking for.

@user110391 more fundamentally I suspect any logic that only allows True/False as values implicitly assumes LNC (basically rejects LEM due to now allowing a third option)

"more fundamentally I suspect any logic that only allows True/False as values implicitly assumes LNC (basically rejects LEM)" Interesting, could you elaborate?

@user110391 the chain of implications is: bivalence —> LEM —> LNC.    See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_bivalence

@user110391 to clarify — if the semantics only allows “True” or “False” for all propositions  then this implies both LNC and LEM

"to clarify — if the semantics only allows “True” or “False” for all propositions then this implies both LNC and LEM" Yeah I figured that's what you meant, and I have thought along these lines before. It is interesting and seems like a different (and valuable) formulation of what other's are saying Aristotle said. If you edit your answer to include this in a more elaborate way, I might accept your answer. Currently, Kristian Berry's answer is the only one that goes into a satisfying degree of explanation of the indemonstrability of the LNC, but your answer about truth-values could rival it.

@user110391 sure thing. If you find this line of thinking helpful I’ll devote some more space to fleshing it out in an addendum to my current answer.

@user110391 updated :)


I have read somewhere that Frege (attempted to) prove the LNC (and the LEM) via the Law of Identity

In Principia Mathematica (1910-1913) the authors proved, from their own set of propositional axioms, the law P.2.08, called the "principle of identity":

p → p.

In P.2.11 they proved "excluded middle": ¬p ∨ p, and in P.3.24 the "law of contradiction": ¬(p∧¬p).
The result is obvious due to the fact that the conditional is not primitive in the Principia: p → q is defined as ¬p ∨ q in Def.1.01 (page 98).
In Begriffsschrift (1879) G,Frege proved the Prop.27 that in modern notation is A → A.
Frege comment is: "We cannot (at the same time) affirm A and deny A". This means that A → A is already the Excluded Middle.
For Frege, the conditional is primitive and it is elucidated through truth conditions: the conditional A → B "means that the possibility that A is affirmed and B is denied does not take place."
Added, Nov.28

By non-trivially unprovable, I mean that unprovable unless proven by virtue of being an axiom.

The above proofs, albeit formally correct, beg the question from an intuitive point of view.
Consider Frege's elucidation of A → B and apply it to A → A: "the possibility that A is affirmed and A is denied does not take place." But this is exactly LNC.
In Classical Logic the principle is there from the start, embedded into the truth-functional definition of connectives and in the assumption that there are two "logical objects": the truth values (see Frege again: the True (das Wahre) and the False (das Falsche)).
(Non)-polemical comment: but LNC "was there from the start" not of mathematical logic, but of formal logic and (Western) philosophy.
See Aristotle's Metaphysics 1011b13:

Let this, then, suffice to show that the most indisputable of all beliefs is that contradictory statements are not at the same time true [...].


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You need to start by understanding what you mean by a proof. A proof has to start from something. If we are proving the conclusion of an argument from its premises then we are starting with the premises and showing that the conclusion follows. If we are proving a theorem in a mathematical theory then we are starting from the axioms of that theory and showing that the theorem follows. If we are proving a theorem of logic itself, then we are starting with the axioms or rules of the logic and showing that the theorem follows.
In each case, we are not proving the starting point, we are proving that the conclusion or the theorem follows from the starting point. If an argument is deductively valid, you are free to dispute the truth of the premises. If a mathematical conjecture is proved to be a theorem, you are at liberty to reject the axioms as being inapplicable and to use different axioms.
Similarly, if a theorem of logic is proved, it does not establish that the theorem is somehow universally correct, only that it follows from the axioms and rules of the logic. If you ask for a justification for why some theorem of logic is correct, there is little value in showing that it follows from some other axioms or theorems of that logic. Doing that just pushes the request for justification back to those axioms. The only value would be if the theorem was highly complex and we needed to see a proof in order to be convinced that it is correct.
So the LNC is not provable without a logic to prove it, and in that sense any proof of LNC can be considered circular. Similarly for any other theorem of logic.
We may take an alternative approach to using a formal proof within a deductive system. We might start from some semantic principles about propositions and their truth values and formulate a theory of semantic consequence. This is, broadly speaking, the approach taken within model theory. We can then prove metatheorems about how a deductive system is sound and complete with respect to that semantic theory. That could be considered a kind of justification of LNC, but it still depends on the assumptions that go into our semantic theory.
Incidentally, in most commonly used deductive systems, LNC is not an axiom, so in that sense there are non-trivial proofs of LNC, but that is hardly an interesting sense. For example, there is a proof of LNC using a Hilbert-style axiom system in the answer to this question. Here is another proof of LNC using natural deduction:
1.  |  P ∧ ¬P          Assumption
2.  |  P ∧ ¬P          1, reiteration
3.  ¬(P ∧ ¬P)          1, 2, negation introduction

It doesn't get much simpler than that. It looks so simple that it must be cheating, but all it is doing is using the rule that if any sentence entails a contradiction then we may introduce its negation. P ∧ ¬P entails itself, so it entails a contradiction. Depending on exactly what rules your deductive system has, you may need to introduce falsum (⊥) first, but the principle is the same.

"So the LNC is not provable without a logic to prove it, and in that sense any proof of LNC can be considered circular. Similarly for any other theorem of logic." In what sense can they  be considered circular? I am (as far as I understand) only concerned with circularity where the conclusion features in the premises, and under this sense, no non-axiom theorem is circularly proven in logic (axioms are  technically also theorems in logics where P → P is valid, but this just a trivial technicality that I mention in order to avoid the annoying "technically, axioms are theorems as well" comment.

I find your proof of LNC from natural deduction interesting (I have thought about this kind of proof but never seen it). However, would not such a proof rely on the principle of explosion (PoE)? Merely asserting that a contradiction exists does not necessarily imply that the negation of any true proposition is also true, unless the logic has the PoE. An in that case, wouldn't the PoE have to feature in the proof? Furthermore, proving something by way of the PoE would be a trivial proof, no? The LNC is a useless theorem in a logic that contains contradictions, no? [1/2]

[2/2] Perhaps "P ∧ ¬P" is a supposition (in the sense of suppositions found in reductio ad absurdum proofs in math), and not an assertion. So, the proof in English would be like: Suppose we have a contradiction. Then, by the PoE, we have the general statement, "contradictions exist." By the PoE, we have the negation of "contradictions exist", also called the LNC. This is a contradiction, therefore, contradictions do not exist." Proving the inexistence of contradictions by reductio ad absurdum would be circular though, but perhaps with the right model theory it works? I have wondered about this

It is circular in the sense that we are presupposing a logic with which to prove it. Without that, any proposed proof could be met with the challenge: how do I know that you cannot prove both LNC and its negation? You have assumed a logic that obeys LNC in the proof of it.

The proof of LNC that I gave does not use the principle of explosion at all. It relies only on the principle of reductio, i.e. that any proposition that implies a contradiction is false. So, in natural deduction proofs, we may assume any proposition we like and if we can derive a contradiction from it then we can use the negation introduction rule to discharge the assumption and leave us with the negation of the assumed proposition. P ∧ ¬P entails itself, so it entails a contradiction and we can introduce its negation.

Aha! That makes more sense, now I know that RAA inference is called negation introduction in natural deduction. But yeah, this example doesn't really count, given that it is just proving the LNC by use of the inference-rule equivalent of the LNC. So, the principle of non-contradictoriness is still simply asserted in this logic, which would be in-line with what people (like Aristotle) say; that the LNC cannot be derived, only assumed as an axiom (or inference rule in this case), in a logic. Others have presumably shown examples to the contrary, but I wonder if there are counter-arguments.


the law of non-contradiction (LNC) is non-trivially unprovable

The law of contradiction just follows logically from the normal semantic of contradictions, conjunctions and negations.
According to the normal semantic of English, a contradiction is the conjunction of two terms, one the negation of the other.
Symbolically:

Φ ∧ ¬Φ

The definition of the negation means that if Φ is true, then ¬Φ is false, and vice versa.
Given this, the definition of the conjunction means that Φ ∧ ¬Φ is necessarily false.
We don't need anything more than that as a proof.
If this is not a proof, then nothing is.

"The definition of the negation means that if Φ is true, then ¬Φ is false, and vice versa." How do you know that Φ isn't both true and false at the same time? Then Φ would be true, and ¬Φ would be true (because Φ is false), so their conjunction would be true. Of course, we take as an axiom that Φ cannot be true and false simultaneously, but the point is that your proof doesn't work without this axiom, and this axiom is the LNC. So although yes it is a proof, the question asks for a non-trivial proof (i.e. one which doesn't use the LNC).

@kaya I think I have explained everything that was required to understand the point, so I don't know what else I could possibly say. You apparently didn't understand my answer, and no amount of additional explaining will be able to change your mind. - 2. "How do you know that Φ isn't both true and false at the same time?" I already said. - 3. "your proof doesn't work without this axiom" Read my answer again. There is no mention of any axiom. - 4. "and this axiom is the LNC" Whatever, my proof doesn't mention any axiom. I wouldn't need any axiom to prove that I have cat.

@Speakpigeon what kind of proof uses no axioms? How do you actually type these things without realizing how bad you sound?

@PW_246 "what kind of proof uses no axioms?" You don't seem understand what a proof is. You presumably believe--like most academics do--that proofs are formal and mathematical in nature. You are deluded. I speak English, you don't. - 2. "How do you actually type these things without realizing how bad you sound?" I should ask this question to academic logicians.

@speakpigeon I’ve had a better time getting AIs to understand logic than you. I even thought you were one or someone’s bot when I first encountered you. You’re not from reality, except for that you exist.

Gosh. I don't always agree with you but I always think that you say things well. I don't get why people are attacking your Answer. "That's not an argument, it's just contradiction!"

@ScottRowe "I don't get why people are attacking your Answer." I contradicts what they are certain is the only reasonable solution they have learnt from a long tradition of seemingly brilliant logicians. They don't have any argument because they don't even want to understand what I say. I can do with a bit of support. Thanks.

Right, I'm not really competent to answer on Logic questions, I'm just a computer programmer. Mainly I want to see all these contentious questions settled absolutely and finally.

@ScottRowe "Mainly I want to see all these contentious questions settled absolutely and finally." I suspect it's going to take them some time yet. You better be, like, really young.
